# Adding new related object to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a blog. With that blog I can send messages and people can react to those messages. To achieve this I have made two models, Messages and Comments. Whereby Messages can have multiple Comments so they have a one to many relationship. Now I am trying to add a new comment to a message but I dont get it working.

When I add a message it returns my view in the catch from my try catch statement.

I have tracked it down to the part where I am trying to bind a value to the foreignkey messagesId in my Comments Model.
This am I doing because I want to assign my comment to one message.

**Here are my models**

```
namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Messages
    {
        public int MessagesId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }

        public Messages()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

namespace Portfolio.Models
{
    public class Comments
    {
        public int CommentsId { get; set; }
        public string Comments_body { get; set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }
        public int ComToMes { get; set; }

        public virtual Messages Messages { get; set; }

        public Comments()
        {
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my controller**

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComments(FormCollection formValues)
    {

        try
        {
            Comments comment = new Comments();
            comment.Comments_body = formValues["editor"];
            var currentMessage 
            =_context.messages.Find(Int32.Parse(formValues["IdName"]));
            comment.Messages.MessagesId = currentMessage.MessagesId;

            _context.comments.Add(comment);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }   
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Blog");
    }
```

**And here is my view**

```
    @*The form to post comments*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComments", "Messages"))
    {
       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Comment</label>
           @Html.TextArea("editor", htmlAttributes: new { name = "editor1", 
           id = "editor", rows = "10", cols = "180" }                                       
           @Html.Hidden("IdName",messages.MessagesId)
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="PostButton">Post 
       Comment</button>
     }
```

Comment: Your `Comments` model needs a navigation property for the `Message` - e.g. `public int MessageId { get; set; }`. but you really need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: One really good tip I can give you is to use the singular for your entity names. `Message` and `Comment`. It really helps with the readability (especially at a glance).

Comment: thnx im going to change that right away @Flater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Comments class you need this property:

Public int MessagesId {get; set; }